# Multiply 2 sparse matrices

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sparse-matrix, rdd, matrix-multiplication

I want to multiply two sparse matrices originating from text files. I currently have this code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf


@SerialVersionUID(123L)
case class M_Matrix ( i: Long, j: Long, v: Double )
extends Serializable {}

@SerialVersionUID(123L)
case class N_Matrix ( j: Long, k: Long, w: Double )
extends Serializable {}

object Multiply {
def main(args: Array[ String ]){
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Multiply")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val M_ = sc.textFile(args(0)).map( line => { val a = line.split(",")
  M_Matrix(a(0).toLong,a(1).toLong,a(2).toDouble) } )

val N_ = sc.textFile(args(1)).map( line => { val a = line.split(",")
  N_Matrix(a(0).toLong, a(1).toLong, a(2).toDouble) } )
val res = M_.map( M_ => (M_.j,M_) )
  .join(N_.map( N_ => (N_.j, N_)))
  .map({case (j, ((i,v),(k,w))) => ((i,k), v * w)})
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .map({ case ((i,k), sum) => (i, k, sum)} )
res.saveAsTextFile(args(2))
sc.stop()
}
}
```

It is giving me an error that * is not a valid operator in v * w.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is nearly correct, some small changes is required to make it work. Specifically, in the `map` done on the matrices before the `join` operation:

```
M_.map( M_ => (M_.j, (M_.i, M_.v))).join(N_.map(N_ => (N_.j, (N_.k, N_.w))))
```

A tuple should be used as values here since in the next statement a tuple is what is expected,

```
.map{ case(j, ((i,v),(k,w))) => ((i,k), v * w)}
```

---

I would recommend trying using the built in functionality in Spark instead, since it should be more efficient. A matrix can be created from a `RDD[MatrixEntry]`. First create the two matrices:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{BlockMatrix, CoordinateMatrix, MatrixEntry}

val M_ = sc.textFile(args(0)).map{ line => 
  val a = line.split(",")
  MatrixEntry(a(0).toLong, a(1).toLong, a(2).toDouble)
}

val N_ = sc.textFile(args(1)).map{ line => 
  val a = line.split(",")
  MatrixEntry(a(0).toLong, a(1).toLong, a(2).toDouble)
}
```

Then convert them both into `BlockMatrix`:

```
val matrix_M = new CoordinateMatrix(M_).toBlockMatrix()
val matrix_N = new CoordinateMatrix(N_).toBlockMatrix()
```

Afterwards, you can simply multiply them using the function `multiply`:

```
val res = matrix_M.multiply(matrix_N)
```

Comment: I have installed scala plugin on intellij. When I use the built in functionality. It is giving errors

Comment: well I changed it a bit of code and it shows `Error:(29, 23) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: edu.uta.cse6331.M_Matrix
      .map({case (j, ((i,v),(k,w))) => ((i,k), v * w)})`

Comment: @SiddhantAttri From your error message, it seems that you don't actually use the `multiply`. canno't resolve BlockMatrix could be that you didn't do the import.

Comment: @SiddhantAttri Yes, it should work for large matrices as well.